# Being notified that I have to log in when editing the logged in account

Tags: support, bug, login, user-accounts, openid

I just created a new account via gmail integration and I'm having problems editing my own information.

I recovered my account and logged out then back in and when I log in I am not prompted for a password or anything, I'm just logged in. Then I try to edit my account information to change my name/birth date/etc and get an error message:

"This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account."

Comment: You probably need to merge the accounts.

Comment: I've sent a message through the contact, thanks.